# openpyxl - style on characters

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to port my code from `pywin32` to `openpyxl`. But I can't find the way to change the color style on partial characters in the cell. In `pywin32`, I can use:
`Range(Cell).GetCharacters(Start, Length).Font.ColorIndex` to do this. But it seems there is no such method like that in `openpyxl`?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that a cell is the smallest item to which you can apply styles to. You can work around this restriction by embedding formatting within the text but this is even messier than it sounds.

Comment: After I read the source code of openpyxl. Yes, I just realized that `openpyxl` didn't consider character formatting at all, which need to have `<rPr>` element inserted in `sharedStrings.xml`. Now it's become the difficult task.

Comment: Yep, I'm planning some changes to the way styles work which **might** make doing something like that a bit easier in the future. But basically the specification is a mess in this area.